# Using reduce and lambda function to find average grade in a dictionary list

Tags: list, function, dictionary, lambda, reduce

In a dictionary list containing student information like name, age, grade. Use lambda and reduce function to find average grade of all students?

I am not able to use the lambda and reduce function to find the average grade in the dictionary list.

Comment: Show us what you have tried.